# php regular expression digits and "/" symbol

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I need a regular expression for a string that contains digits and "/" symbol. I am new to regular expressions and I don`t know how to set the rule about "/" symbol. Thanks for replies.

Comment: The rule is to write it properly which depends on how you want to use that character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following expression:

```
[\d/]+
```

Allows digits and the forward slash.

Comment: Shouldn't you escape the `/`?

Comment: Thanks. So for example if I need uppercase letters with @$* symbols I can just write [A-Z@$*]. Am I right?

Comment: Escaping the / is only required if the raw string itself is delimited by slashes.  In php, this can take any form, such as: '#[\d/]+#', but if forward slashes are used, as in '/[\d\/]+/', then yes it would need to be escaped.  Of course, given the usage of the forward slash, I find it more readable to use a different delimiter.

Answer (score 1):

```
'/[\d\/]+/'
```

Should work for both digits and /.

Comment: but if I escape / symbol like you did here google chrome gives This webpage is not available error.

Comment: Well, it's not a web address, its a regular expression. Where are you trying to enter the expression?

Comment: In the php file :) I am new to regular expressions not to web programming.

Comment: Escaping in the expression should just tell the engine to use the literal "/" symbol, since it's normally a reserved symbol. It should not actually appear anywhere outside of the expression. What is the PHP error message, or is there not one?

Comment: it just says This webpage is not available
The connection to localhost was interrupted. without escaping web page is opened normally.

Comment: Well, that might indicate a PHP error. Is there an error message generated?

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the '/'. The reason is that the '/' has other significance in regular expressions. Just simply write `\/`, or, int the context of a regular expression: `[\d\/]+`.

Comment: The / doesn't have significance to regex in php; it's just that convention has the delimiters typically follow how other languages have regex, e.g., '/[\d\/]+/' in JS, but is identical in functionality to '#[\d/]+#' in PHP.

Comment: That's true, but the reason that you need to escape the '/' is because '/' is used to start and end regexes in other languages.

Comment: More often not, though.  In JS, yes, forward slashes uniquely identify a regex string, but in python it is quoted, .net is quoted, mysql is quoted, and Java itself offers the regex package which has quoted strings as well.  JS and the direct delimiter fashion is more minority, as I see it.